# Django REST serializer queryset: access model via reverse foreign key?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I have a table that I would like to display the drawdown amounts for multiple pension funds for a proposed Investment. I have written a for loop over the 'Investment' instance in my table. However, I cannot seem to retrieve the amounts from this loop. I think that my queryset 'amountdrawdown' is incorrect as I'm trying to reverse lookup a foreign key (from the Investment model to DrawdownOnFund model).

My models.py, simplified:

```
class PensionFund(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField() 

class PensionFundDeposit(models.Model):
    PensionFund = models.ForeignKey(PensionFund)
    date = models.DateField()
    amount = models.DecimalField()
    undrawn = models.DecimalField()

class Investment(models.Model):          <---- Looping over this
    amount = models.DecimalField()
    date = models.DateField()

class DrawdownOnFund(models.Model):
    Investment = models.ForeignKey(Investment) 
    PensionFund = models.ForeignKey(PensionFund)
    date = models.DateField()
    amount = models.DecimalField()   <---- I would like to retrieve this
```

My serializer.py, simplified:

```
class PensionFundSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ['id', 'name']

class PensionFundDepositSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ['id', 'fund','date','amount','undrawn', 'fundname']

class InvestmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    amountdrawdown = serializers.CharField(source='drawdown.amount')  <---My attempt to write a query to retrieve the amount
    class Meta:
        fields = ['id', 'amount', 'date', 'amountdrawdown']

class DrawdownOnFundSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ['id', 'call', 'commitment', 'date', 'amount', 'callid']
```

Comment: `Investment` instance will have a list of `DrawdownOnFund` model instance not a single instance, in reverse relationship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Investment` -> `DrawdownOnFund` is having 1-Many relationship. So, `DrawdownonFund` will have relationship with one of the `Investment` instance. And, in reverse class(i.e `Investment`) will have a list of `DrawdownOnFund` instances by name of reverse lookup field is `drawdownonfund_set`(by default).

So, considering that case, you want to show list of all drawdownonfunds related to one invesment, you should use nested serializer pattern.

```py
class DrawdownOnFundSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ['id', 'call', 'commitment', 'date', 'amount', 'callid']

class InvestmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    amountdrawdowns = DrawdownOnFundSerializer(many=True, source='drawdownonfund_set')
    class Meta:
        fields = ['id', 'amount', 'date', 'amountdrawdowns']
```

Deserialize output of one instance of `Investment` model will look like this.
You can control the fields to be shown of each item in `amountdrawdowns` by managing `DrawdownOnFundSerializer`.

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "amount": "",
  "date": "",
  "amountdrawdowns": [
    {
      "id": "",
      "call": "",
      "commitment": "",
      "date": "",
      "amount": "",
      "callid": ""
    }  
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
from django.db import models
from user.models import User

# Create your models here.


class SocielPost(models.Model):
    """
    This Model Is Created For Upload The POST
    """
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class PostTag(models.Model):
    """
    This Model Is Created For Tag User
    """
    tag_post = models.ForeignKey(SocielPost,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tag_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.tag_post)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].